# Renaming files in an output folder

Tags: vba

I am using two folders. The first is for input where all the input files are and the other is an output folder where the renamed files are to be saved.

Please see below for the code. I'm using the `Str()` function to convert a numeric value, but it's not working, why I do not know. Also I'm not getting the required output.

`Str(m)` is not working and shows type mismatching error.

```
Sub ChangeFilename()

IFILEPATH = InputBox("Copy INPUT folder PATH")
OFILEPATH = InputBox("Copy OUTPUT folder PATH")
Dim strfile As String
Dim filenum As String

strfile = Dir(IFILEPATH)
startFile = InputBox("Start File NAME")
endFile = InputBox("End File NAME")
Dim r As Long
r = InputBox("Input INCREAMENT valu")
Do While strfile <> ""
    If (strfile = startFile) Then
        Do While strfile <= endFile
            x = Left(strfile, Len(strfile) - 4)
            x = Right(x, Len(x) - 2)
            y = Val(x)
            If y > 0 Or y < 9 Then
                Dim m As Long
                m = y + r
                Dim k As String
                'MsgBox Str(m)
                k = Str(m)        'This is the area where I am facing problem i.e Str(m) not WORKING and shows type mismatching Error
                x = "00" & k
                Name IFILEPATH & strfile As OFILEPATH & "eq" & x & ".eps"
            ElseIf y >= 9 Or y < 99 Then
                m = y + r
                x = "0" & k
                Name IFILEPATH & strfile As OFILEPATH & "eq" & x & ".eps"
            Else
                'x = Str(Val(x + r))
                Name IFILEPATH & strfile As OFILEPATH & "eq" & x & ".eps"
            End If
        Loop
    End If
    strfile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Also, your code is full of undeclared variables. Please look up the `Option Explicit` command. If used, it will eliminate a lot of unexpected errors.

Answer (score 1):

If converting the Long to a string is your only problem, I think you are looking for the CStr() function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx